# Scala, How to traverse through sequence

Tags: scala

I have a `Seq[Object]` and I want to iterate through each object and check if one of its boolean properties are true/false. I've tried to use `flatmap` followed by `filter` but it's not working:

```
val systemResourcesExpandable = host.systemResources flatMap (.child) filter { childseq => 
   for { 
      child <- childseq; 
      child.config flatMap (.cpuAllocation) flatMap (_.expandableReservation) 
   } yield { child } 
}
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your code, and explain what exactly is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming an object like the following

```
case class MyObject(intProp: Int, boolProp: Boolean)
```

and a sequence like this

```
val mySequence = Seq(obj1, obj2, obj3)
```

You would then use the following logic to filter out false boolean conditions on boolProp

```
mySequence.filter(x => x.boolProp)
```

This operation return a new sequence with only the objects that have a boolProp of true. Note, this does not *modify* the sequence, but instead returns a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have the following:

```
case class Stuff(p: Int, b: Boolean = false)
```

And you create a list of these guys:

```
val x = List(Stuff(1), Stuff(2), Stuff(3, true))
```

Now if you want to find out if one of them has `b` set to `true`, you just do:

```
x.exists(_.b)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation !!

Answer (score 0):

```
 val systemResourcesExpandable : Option[Seq[SystemResources.Child]] = host.systemResources flatMap (_.child)  filter { childseq =>
    for{
         child <- childseq;
        expandablereservation  <-child.config flatMap (_.cpuAllocation) flatMap (_.expandableReservation)
        if (expandablereservation)

    } yield {
        child
    }
  }
```

This is my code snippet, i am new to scala ..i am getting a error for type mismatch here ...saying that expected is boolean.. Child has property of expandable reservation is it is true then only extract that child from the sequence of childs

Comment: @Ren can u please look at this and help

Comment: Don't post new questions as answers. Please update your original question.